# Elimination and exchanging rows

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Solve by elimination, exchanging rows when necessary

$$
    v + w = 0\\
u + v = 0\\
u + v + w = 1\\
$$

Which permutation matrix is required?

answer is

$$
P=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Is the answer wrong since there isn't a 1 in the 3rd row, which deletes the 3rd row. But answer says this is the permutation matrix, I believe the permutation matrix should be =

$$
P=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Anyway I hope the "1" in the answer paged didn't appear for some reason. Nevermind let's pass this issue and move forward

When you write the coefficent matrix

$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

You have to find some

$$
P
$$
I get it but do we have to find P because

$$
A_{1,1} = 0
$$
Or is there some other reason for this?

My other question is after some procedures there is no way we can reach a upper triangle form here. As far as I remember in a upper triangle form(U) the 1st line should have 3 coefficent 2nd line should have 2 and the 3rd line should have 1 coefficent. But in this question since there are zeros in specific positions we can't form such a triangle. For example when we take the permutation matrix the answer sheet says (the permutation matrix i stated above) We don't get into a upper triangle position. How come is this the case?

Guys please help, I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: Can you please make clear what the **answer** says about the permutation matrix (the last 2 lines of your question)? I will edit as required

Comment: I explained it,  I said answer is =  ....

Comment: I wanted explanation of your last two lines. Anyways, check if my modified answer is of any help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you have to find $P$ because $A_{1,1}=0$ (otherwise how will you divide by $A_{1,1}$ in the pivoting step?)

As far as I think, you are concerned about the $LU$ decomposition of a matrix where $L$ is lower triangular and $U$ upper triangular. Well the fact is , there always exists a permutation matrix such that $PA=LU$ and this decomposition is uniquely determined.

The permutation matrix is just the identity matrix(with row interchanges if required). Often what happens is that the pivot ( in a certain pivoting step) becomes zero (due to previous pivoting) or  is zero from beginning.So to force $A_{ii}$ to become the pivot at the $i^{th}$ step, the matrix is then multiplied with a permutation matrix so as to interchange the $i^{th}$ row with the row which contains the maximum element of column $i$. $P$ for that step is just the **identity** matrix with the corresponding two rows interchanged.

EDIT: Doubt clearance

> What do you mean by the "pivoting step" I couldn't get that.

In a LU factorisation ,what you usually do is (at the $i^{th}$pivoting step)

Step 1. Divide the all the elements $A_{i,j|j\in\{i,i+1,\cdots,n\}}$ by $A_{i,i}$ thus making $A_{i,i}=1$

Step 2. **Sweep out all the elements of column $i$** by performing the operation $A_{k,*|k\in\{i+1,\cdots,n\}}=A_{k,*}-A_{k,i}\times A_{i,*}$ . So you see all the elements below $A_{i,i}$ become zero.

(Hence if somehow $A_{i+1,i+1}$ becomes zero in the $i^{th}$ pivoting step , then pivoting at $(i+1)^{th}$ step would be impossible, hence the need of $P$)

> A doesnt have a zero pivot but U does

You see, actually the method we are following **doesn't allow $U$ to have a $0$ at any diagonal point**. The process I described above(the most common and accepted one) makes sure every element of the diagonal of $U$ is $1$.(Step 1.)

> PPA = LPU?

It doesn't make sense.  If you study **the proof** of why and how the $PA=LU$ factorisation works, the you will see that for any two permutation matrices $P_1,P_2$

1. $P_1\cdot P_2=$ a permutation matrix
2. $P_1\cdot P_2^{-1}=$ a permutation matrix
3. $LP=PL$ ($L$ is a lower/upper triangular matrix)
4. det($P$)$=1$

So $$PPA=LPU\implies P'A=LU$$ for some permutation matrix $P'$

Comment: This is not an answer, more of a comment

Comment: Thanks for your edit made a lot of sense. What do you mean by the "pivoting step" I couldn't get that.

Comment: And so I understand that U from LU doesn't have any zero pivots right? Because PA = LU. But there are some cases where A doesnt have a zero pivot but U does, then PPA = LPU ??? can we say that?

Comment: @Xenidia Edited .. Hope will suit you better. Please don't forget to accept..

Comment: Thanks It made everything clear now :)